# How to find equilibrium price with inverse demand?

Tags: price, equilibrium

So I know how to do it when it is a function of Q but as a function of P I'm confused about what steps I have to take

demand:
p = 1000-0.025q

supply:
p=150+0.033q

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where users must demonstrate effort using text, markdown syntax and/or images space provided in the text of his question submission for the site. Using only images as proof of work is insufficient. for more details see:https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions